# give error if number is anything other than 1 or 0

Tags: php

```
<?php
$gender = 0;
if (($gender != 0) || ($gender != 1))
{
    die('error:Must select a gender.');
}
?>
```

This should give a error if the gender is anything other than `1` or `0`. So if i gave `5` it should die. If i gave it `1` it should not die. If i give it `0` it should not die.

I was thinking about a few work arounds

```
<?php
$gender = 0;
if ($gender == 0)
{
//number is okay
}
else if ($gender == 1)
{
//number is okay
}
else
{
die('error:Must select a gender.');
}
?>
```

Well that looks sloppy and it would work or i could create a array with 0 and 1 and check if its in it or not. Kinda overkill i think.

Not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: If you're able to make gender an unsigned integer, you could just check if($gender > 1){die('etc.');}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the wrong boolean operator:

```
 if (($gender != 0) || ($gender != 1)) {
 }
```

This will be entered if gender is 0, too, because it isn't 1, and vice versa. What you need to do is:

```
 if (($gender != 0) && ($gender != 1)) {
 }
```

Look at this table:

```
gender  A (gender != 0)    B (gender != 1)     A || B     A && B
----------------------------------------------------------------
0       false              true                true       false
1       true               false               true       false
5       true               true                true       true
```

Also note Joshua's suggestion in the comments:

```
if (($gender == 0) || ($gender == 1)) {
    /* number is ok */
} else {
    die();
}
```

which is a bit longer, but more readable.

Comment: Doing `if (($gender == 0) || ($gender == 1)) { /* number is ok */ } else { die(); }` would work as well.

Comment: @Joshua: Yes, and it's more readable. I edited and suggested this.

Comment: Thank you. I get it know! I feel kinda stupid but i understand now. Will know for later. Still learning, on my own.

Comment: Boolean algebra can be difficult to wrap your head around at the beginning, so there's no need to feel stupid :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (($gender != 0) && ($gender != 1))
                   ^^
```

You want to die if both tests are true.

Answer (score 1):

Change the *or* (`||`) to *and* (`&&`) and it should work, as you only want to fail, when it’s both not `0` and not `1`.